How can I stop l3build deleting files generated by a custom target?
(Silly) MNWE:
build.lua:
ctanpkg = "mini"
module = "mini"
installfiles = {"*.sty", "*.cls", "*.sup"}
tdslocations = {
        "tex/latex/mini/*.sup"
}
function mmake()
        local myfile = myfile or "myfile.sup"
        os.execute("/usr/bin/printf %b \"Hylo eto!\\n\" > myfile.sup")
        cp(myfile,maindir,unpackdir)
        return 0
end
ntarg = "mm"
target_list[ntarg] = {
  func = mmake,
  desc = "Creates TeX font file",
}
--  vim: ts=2:sw=2:tw=80

l3build unpack followed by l3build mm correctly populates build/unpacked. However, if I then run l3build doc, l3build obliterates everything and insists on starting over. Building the documentation requires mini.sup and myfile.sup, where the latter is created by the target mm and the former is generated from the .dtx. Since myfile.sup is gone, compilation obviously fails.
I could add mmake to the doc_init and check_init hooks. However, that would severely limit the packages I could reasonably use l3build for because it is just too expensive to regenerate the files every time I need to rerun a test or find a typo in the docs. There are plenty of cases where the generated files are fine, but the docs need tweaking. Or the sty needs alteration. So I don't want unpack to delete these files either.
Should mmake copy the files somewhere else once they are created? Into a sub-directory of sourcedir, maybe? And then add them to the sources for typesetting/check/doc/whatever?
I can see that might work, but it seems like a rather circuitous route and I'm not really convinced I understand what l3build will and will not obliterate.
What I would really like is an option to tell l3build that it should never delete files of certain types unless explicitly told to do so. (Or just never and I'll remove them manually if necessary.) But I don't think that kind of option exists?
[I do understand that l3build is really designed for the LaTeX team, so I'm open to an answer which just says I should put up or shut up.]
mini.dtx:
% \iffalse meta-comment
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% mini.dtx
% Precursor, foreword, premonition.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \fi
%
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\ProvidesFile{mini.dtx}[1066-01-01]
\documentclass[11pt,british]{ltxdoc}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\usepackage{mini}
\begin{document}
\DocInput{mini.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
%
% The answer you seek is 42.
%
% \minitestcmd
%
% \miniloadcmd
%
% \MaybeStop{%
% \PrintChanges
% \PrintIndex
% }
%
% \section{Implementation}
%
% You do not need to read the remainder of this document in order to install
% or use the fonts.
%
% \iffalse
%<*sty>
% \fi
%    \begin{macrocode}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mini}[1066-01-01]
\def\minitestcmd{But what is the question?}
\def\miniloadcmd{\input{myfile.sup}}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \iffalse
%</sty>
% \fi
%
% \subsection{Supplement}
%
% \iffalse
%<*drv>
% \fi
%    \begin{macrocode}
Hylo Byd!
%    \end{macrocode}
% \iffalse
%</drv>
% \fi
%\Finale

mini.ins:
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent

%% ???
\usedir{tex/latex/mini}

\declarepreamble\safonol
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Preface, preamble, forward.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\endpreamble   

\usepreamble\safonol

\generate{\file{mini.sty}{\from{mini.dtx}{sty}}
  \file{mini.sup}{\from{mini.dtx}{drv}}
}
  
\endbatchfile

PS Apologies for using a non-cross-platform function as an example. My actual function is (possibly) cross-platform, but it requires a bunch of additional files.
PPS If you are curious as to why: https://github.com/latex3/l3build/discussions/362.

first line of build.lua ? build.lua mini.dtx mini.dtx myfile.sup

I ran l3build unpack then l3buld mm and build/unpacked/myfile.sup got built but l3build doc deletes it as you say but doesn't use it so completes without error, is that what you expected?

arguably it could be l3build doc --dirty to skip the clean step but dirty is only documented (and only implemented) for skipping clean with check

@DavidCarlisle I screwed up the example and made it work. It should fail now.

@DavidCarlisle Sorry about the example.

If the builtin targets won't do what you want, you can just replace them entirely with your own code; that's what I do at least. l3build has some nice helper functions and testing features, so it's still much easier than writing a Lua script from scratch.

@MaxChernoff Yes, but your ability to write a Lua script somewhat outstrips mine :).

If you add the function
function cleandir (d)
print "no cleaning today"
end

to build.lua
Then
build/unpacked/myfile.sup

survives l3build doc
That may be a bit more drastic than you need, you could for example use the original function unless --dirty is used or  some other trigger.

Thanks. It feels like a choice of sledgehammers?

Would it be better to just move them and then have them copied back? I don't have a sense of how this is supposed to work.

@cfr I was just checking the outcome was as you wanted, as I put under a comment I don't think it would be unreasonable for l3build doc --dirty to do what you want and build the doc without cleaning up first. but it doesn't (it could easily) as it is since the feature is basically not there you need to over-ride something with a sledgehammer, but adding --dirty wouldn't need force at all, just an if  adding in one place to guard the call to clean (as is done for l3build check) See what Joseph thinks:-)

I guess log a feature request (I'm away for a couple of weeks so might not get round to this otherwise)

@JosephWright Moving and copying back works well. Do you still want me to log a request?

Should I accept this answer even though I'm using a different solution? While your solution would work, there are cases where I also want to regenerate the .sty or the docs, even though the fonts are fine. Using a keepdir means I can keep the fonts while starting over for everything else. It is also less error prone than a solution which relies on me remembering to use --dirty. I'd rather deletion not be a default I have to override.

feel free to post a second answer, I can live without the 15 points:-)
